# CloudFlare won't let in even though I solve the captcha correctly

Tags: tails, blocked-services

Usually when I try to reach sites from Tails, it often get CloudFlare's captcha, and after solving it the sites work for about 10 minutes.

But now it behaves like if the captcha is entered incorrectly each time. I've tried more than 20 times, on multiple sites.

Is it something broken in CloudFlare, in browser or there is some subtile policy change that blocks all Tor users pretending they never can solve the captcha?

**Update**: The issue seems to be re-opened. Where can I report CloudFlare problems to CloudFlare *from within* TAILS?

Comment: It seems that Cloudflare works on their infrastructure. See this tweet for example: https://twitter.com/octal/status/557451680519041024 So your problem might relate to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out Cloudflare is doing some changes on their infrastructure, [ongoing discussion](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2015-January/036531.html) on the tor-talk mailing list.

Situation should be [fixed soon](https://twitter.com/octal/status/557415774185590784).

Comment: Just been fixed, a Cloudflare dev just wrote it on IRC